# I need to find a solution for $2x+\arcsin x=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$2x+\arcsin x=1$$
I didn't find way to solve this problems.
Is there a difference in solving equations between $\sin$ and $\arcsin$?
For some reason I did not find the special solutions of arc.

Is there a connection to Maclaurin or Taylor?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This isn't an equation that can be solved analytically. The best one can do is a judicious approximation or numerical solution.

Comment: You really have to tell us where this equation comes from (smells the homework) to direct you to an appropriate solution.

Comment: Use MacLaurin for a good approximation using very, very few terms.

Answer (score 1):

$$2x+\arcsin x=1$$
Write as $$\arcsin x=-2x+1$$
and look for intersecton of the graphs
$$
\begin{cases}
y=\arcsin x\\
y= -2x+1\\
\end{cases}
$$
In the picture below we see that there is an intersection $x_0\approx 0.3$

To find a more precise approximation we can use the Newton method to find a root of the function $$f(x)=2x+\arcsin x-1$$

Let's say we want a solution with $6$ exact decimal.
Define $$x_0=0.3;\;x_n=x_{n-1}-\frac{f(x_{n-1}}{f'(x_{n-1})}$$
We go on iterating until the difference $|x_n-x_{n-1}|<10^{-6}$

We get the following table
$$
\begin{array}{l|r|r}
 n & a_n & error\\
\hline
 0 & 0.3 &  \\
 1 & 0.331266 & 0.0312659 \\
 2 & 0.331208 & 0.0000577448 \\
 3 & 0.331208 & 2.1\times 10^{-10}\\
\end{array}
$$

The solution is then $x=0.331208$

---

$$...$$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:
$$2x-\frac \pi2\leq 2x+\arcsin(x)\leq 2x+\frac \pi2$$
So we want that:
$$2x-\frac \pi2\leq 1\leq 2x+\frac \pi2$$
And by solving this two disequations you get:
$$\frac 12-\frac \pi4 \leq x \leq \frac 12+\frac \pi4$$
But $arcsin$ is defined only in $[-1,1]$, so:
$$\frac 12-\frac \pi4 \leq x \leq 1$$
So your (eventual) zero(es) are in the interval $I=[\frac 12-\frac \pi4,1[$(you can clearly exclude $1$ verifying by yourself). Moreover the function $f(x)=2x+\arcsin(x)$ is derivable in $I$ and its derivative is:
$$2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
That is always $>0$ so the function is strictly increasing. Moreover since the function $f$ is continous in the interval and $f(\frac 12-\frac \pi2)-1<0$ while $f(1)-1>0$, by Bolzano theorem there must be a solution in the interval(and it's unique because the function is strictly increasing. Now that we have proved that the solution exists and is unique, to find it we have to use numerical methods.
As you said Mac-Lauren series is a possibility since $\arcsin$ is analytical,in particular the best possible choice(that would make the equation analitically solvable) would be:

$\arcsin(x)\approx x+\frac{x^3}{6}$

But to not mess with cubic equations we have to use:

$\arcsin(x) \approx x$

So:

$2x+\arcsin(x) \approx  3x$

And our equation becomes:

$3x\approx 1$

$x\approx \frac 13$

That is already pretty near(you can check). We could also continue and this time we can center the taylor series in $\frac 13$ to improve the approximation(By Peano theorem error in taylor series asimptotically decreases when we get more near to the center).

$\arcsin(x)\approx \arcsin'(1/3)x=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}x$

So our equation becomes:

$(\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}+2)x\approx 1$

$x\approx \frac{4}{3\sqrt{2}+8}$

If you continue this way the approximation will become better and better(this is actually the Newton-Raphson method "simplifed", and in general the convergence to the root is not granted: I simplified a lot)

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$y=2x+\sin^{-1}(x)=3x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ (2 n)! }{4^n(2 n+1) (n!)^2}x^{2 n+1}$$ Truncate the summation and use series reversion to obtain
$$x = \sum_{n=0}^p a_n\,t^{2n+1} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac y 3$$ where the first $a_n$'s make the sequence
$$\left\{1,-\frac{1}{18},-\frac{17}{1080},-\frac{793}{136080},-\frac{72161}{29393280}
   ,-\frac{10829449}{9699782400},-\frac{2424554513}{4539498163200}\right\}$$

Using $y=1$, so $t=\frac 13$, this would give as an *estimate*
$$x \sim \frac{2397094567444716499}{7237426330047513600} \sim 0.331208147500$$ while the solution obtained by Newton method is
$0.331208147481$